# adding an object to a dictionary from another class c#

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that adds a Handscanner to a dictionary if you click on a button. If you click the button, it tells you to scan a barcode in order to get the VID/HID from the Scanner and then add it with `new Scanner("...","...")`, to the dict.
In the class `FrmSettings` I have this method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    Info Gerade = new Info();
    Gerade.ShowDialog();
    FrmMenu fm = new FrmMenu();
    strGerade = fm.DevIDNewScanner;
    fm.Scanners.Add(fm.DevIDNewScanner, new Scanner("dev1", "even"));
    Gerade.Dispose();
}
```

FrmMenu is the class where the Dictionary is implemented. It seems like i'm doing something wrong because after i clicked on the button, the program doesn't accept the scans made by the new scanner. I don't even get an error to investigate further.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and assume that you have two different `FrmMenu` instances? The new one that you're creating in `button1_Click` and then another one elsewhere. Am I correct?

Comment: yep you're right. i have another instance of FrmMenu in the main. if my attempt is not the way - how can i get access to the dict? I'm very new to c# and also in coding in general